# Convert PostgreSQL ARRAY_AGG query to Pandas DataFrame code

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, pandas-groupby

This is PostgreSQL query and I want it to write it using Pandas data-frame.

```sql
SELECT
    A.id,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
        B.b_id,
        C.c_id,
        C.code,
        c.desc
    )) AS conditions
FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id 
JOIN C ON B.b_id = C.c_id
```

The result will look like this when converted to JSON Format using `df.to_json(r'output.json', orient='records')`

```
[
    "id": 123
    "conditions": [
        {
            "b_id": 23,
            "c_id": 23,
            "code": "some secret",
            "desc": "blah blah"
        },
        {
            "b_id": 24,
            "c_id": 24,
            "code": "secret code",
            "desc": "this is description"
        }
    ]
]
```

This is my code so far

```py
import pandas as pd

Adf = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123]})
Bdf = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123, 123], 'b_id': [23, 24]})
Cdf = pd.DataFrame({'c_id': [23, 24], 'code': ['some secret', 'secret code'], 'desc': ['blah blah', 'this is description']})

df = Adf.merge(Bdf, left_on='id', right_on='id', how='inner')

df = df.merge(Cdf, left_on='b_id', right_on='c_id', how='inner')

print(df)
```

Which gives output-

```
    id  b_id  c_id         code                 desc
0  123    23    23  some secret            blah blah
1  123    24    24  secret code  this is description
```

I don't know how to perform ARRAY_AGG.

Comment: you should supply the tables A,B,C,D as well as the expected output. Also, state what you tried.

Comment: @sammywemmy I have added what I have done so far and the structure of DataFrames.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I am running into the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in a DataFrame structure you have to dissolve the `ARRAY_AGG` because the DataFrame do not support this structure.

```
SELECT
    A.id,
    B.b_id,
    C.c_id,
    C.code,
    C.desc
FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id 
JOIN C ON B.b_id = C.c_id
```

And then you can execute the Pandas command.

Comment: What pandas command would you then do?  I am also stuck on this.